# Review queue for posts without any votes

Tags: feature-request, voting

There seems to be a lot of posts that don't get any up/down votes. I think it would be a good idea to have a review queue just for unvoted posts where the action options are just to upvote or downvote. Do you guys think it would be worthwhile?

Comment: why would you want to force votes? the question may not deserve either. What is the **value** here?

Comment: This assumes that every question deserves either a downvote or an upvote. This is definitely not true; certain questions can be quite mediocre.

Comment: *not voting* is itself voting which means I don't think it's a very good question to deserve a vote but not that bad to deserve a negative one.

Comment: Do you intend answers to enter the queue as well? If so, it is going to be skewed towards upvotes since the current system disincentivizes downvotes on answers by punishing the voters with deduced rep (it may not matter objectively, but psychologically - it does).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, no...

The quality rating takes into account zero-scored posts as well as part of a well-received calculation, so if someone just posts a whole bunch post questions which have zero votes on it entirely, then the system would still recognize that the questions they're asking aren't all that good.

However, there is something to be said about low trafficked tags and niche technologies (I'm looking at you [prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog)) which don't get a lot of traffic, which will *never* change no matter what anyone does.  So there's some sympathy that goes out for people who answer questions in those fields.

But even *then*, just having a queue where people would be more willing than they already are to go on overdrive either upvoting or downvoting everything they see would be highly detrimental to the site.  We would no longer have a quality rating ***at all*** if that happened.